# "Вот именно(,) что"

Tags: запятые

"Вот именно(,) что нам не по восемнадцать, время назад не запустишь".

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В книге "Новый объяснительный словарь синонимов русского языка" (Ю. Апресян и др., изд РАН, 2000) в словарную статью на "именно" есть такой абзац:

> *Именно* в небрежной разговорной речи используется в составе устойчивого выражения **вот именно что**, обычно в полемическом
> контексте.

В приводимых авторами примерах запятая отсутствует (в свете трактовки выражения как устойчивого оно фактически приведено и как *неизменяемое*),

> Ср. *- У тебя же были деньги! - Вот именно что были! Неделю назад.*
>
> *-Тебе вот именно что сорок лет! - возмущенно сказал Король* (Ю.Визбор, Завтрак с видом на Эльбрус)
>
> *Вот именно что вторые сутки гости* (Л.Петрушевская, Уроки музыки)

Если обратиться к издательской пратике, то картина выглядит сложнее: если выражением присоединяется неполное высказывание (буквальная цитата из реплики собеседника), то да, запятая не ставится. Если же добавляется законченное предложение, то в  ряде случаев (когда присоединяется не просто цитата из чужой реплики) ставят запятую:

> *— Вот именно, что это было бы слишком простое объяснение!* (А. Аверченко, Публика)

В вашем случае больше похоже на цитирование реплики (даже если оно с прямым отрицанием), поэтому можно обойтись без запятой.

Answer (score 3):

***Вот Именно, что** нам не по восемнАдцать, время назад не запУстишь.*

Я выбрала обособленный вариант как более подходящий, так как союз ЧТО  относится **к предложению, а не к слову**. В то же время  вариант без обособления в принципе также возможен.

**1. Способ решения**

Я полагаю, что Новый объяснительный словарь синонимов русского языка" (Ю. Апресян и др., изд РАН, 2000) **вряд ли можно применить для решения этой задачи.** Это можно видеть из конкретных примеров в Нацкорпусе, где частотность вариантов с обособлением и без обособления примерно равная и на выводы словаря **явно не ориентирована.**

Поэтому нужно провести **грамматический анализ** сочетания, а также сделать вывод из **практических примеров**.

**2. Решение.**

Слова ВОТ, ИМЕННО – это частицы,  они образуют составную частицу ВОТ ИМЕНнО.  которая обычно относятся к знаменательным словам и не обособляется от них.

В сочетании ВОТ ИМЕННО ЧТО  слово ЧТО является **изъяснительным союзом**. Поэтому  ВОТ ИМЕННО ЧТО  может относиться как к предложению или словосочетанию, так и к слову.

Здесь интонационное решение, связанное **с логическим выделением** сочетания ВОТ ИМЕННО. **При обособлении** сначала подчеркиваем ВОТ ИМЕННО, а потом раскрываем содержание предложения или указываем на слово, а  при **отсутствии обособления** сразу переходим к содержанию.

Соответственно, при указании **на слово** чаще встречается необособленный вариант, а при указании **на предложение** или распространенное словосочетание  ВОТ ИМЕННО обычно обособляется.

3. **Примеры** (в Нацкорпусе  124 примера)

**Вот именно что** цирк, нет ничего лучше, чем танцы русских медведей, жестокие укротители и печальные клоуны. [Александр Иличевский.  (2009)]

«Этого я могу достичь и без них». «**Вот именно что** без них. Ты хочешь быть один на земле?»  2012]

― Вот именно, ― подхватил директор, ― **вот именно, что** он археолог. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 1 (1964)]

― **Вот именно, что** не знаю, ― возбудившись, говорил Монахов. [Андрей Битов. Лес (1960-1980)]

**Вот именно, что** не они взяли, а мы отдали ― Бабуров ваш! [Константин Симонов. Так называемая личная жизнь/ Четыре шага (1956-1965)]

**Вот именно, что** ничего даже нет смешного и остроумного, а просто ― жестоко и глупо». [В. В. Вересаев. Аполлон и Дионис (1914)]